# Orthocenter and vectors

Tags: vectors

Given three vectors $a,b,c$ which are linearly independent, and since there's a dot product $<,>$, I gotta prove that the orthocenter $h$ exists and it's unique.

I really have no idea how to do it. The professor gave us a hint about drawing in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, what I did, but for me, every triangle I draw with these vectors will make them linearly *dependent*, which goes against the hypothesis.

Comment: Are we talking about vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$? In that case, take the plane containing these three vectors. Your problem now reduces to a very basic theorem in Euclidean Geometry.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if it's in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: The trick works either way. Do you know how to prove orthocenters exist in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: No, and I can't see how to work using three vectors.

Comment: You can prove orthocenters of plane triangles by using cyclic quadrilaterals. Or by Ceva’s Theorem. Or its trigonometric variant. Or by drawing parallels to each side from the other vertex and proving that the circumcenter of the triangle you create is the point you want. There are countless proofs, easily available online. Once you have that, since three points define a plane, you’re immediately done with your more general problem.

Comment: But how three linearly independent vectors can create a triangle? I mean, the only image I can see it's taking them from a same origin and then using their others extremes to be the triangle's vertices, is it right?

Comment: Are you seeing vectors as points or as arrows? In the former case, you’re creating a triangle. In the latter, how would you even define the orthocenter of three vectors?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm here asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points determine a plane, so it suffices to prove this for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The set of vectors $x$ such that $(a-x)\cdot(b-c)=0$ determines a line. Likewise, $(b-x)\cdot(c-a)=0$ determines another line. If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not collinear, these lines will not be parallel, and determine a unique intersection, $h$. To prove our original claim, it thus suffices to prove that $(c-h)\cdot(a-b)=0$. And we can do this by noticing the following chain of equalities: $$(c-h)\cdot(a-b)=$$ $$a\cdot c-b\cdot c-a\cdot h+b\cdot h=$$ $$-((a\cdot b-a\cdot c-b\cdot h+c\cdot h)+(b\cdot c-a\cdot b-c\cdot h+a\cdot h))=$$ $$(a-h)\cdot(b-c)+(b-h)\cdot(c-a)=0.$$